# PDO DAO PHP duvida no insert

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando fazer uma insert usando pdo e dao, tenho pouco conhecimento no caso, fiz em cima de um modelo que funciona muito bem, só que quando faço com mais campos e outro banco o código não dá erro, mas não retorna nada e não faz o insert.

```
public function insert() {

    $sql = new Sql();

    $results = $sql->select("CALL sp_clientes_insert(:NOME, :EMAIL, :SENHA, :TELEFONE, :ENDERECO, :CPF, :COMPLEMENTO, :NUMERO, :BAIRRO, :CIDADE, :ESTADO, :CEP)" ,
    array(
        ':NOME'=>$this->getNome(),
        ':EMAIL'=>$this->getEmail(),
        ':SENHA'=>$this->getSenha(),
        ':TELEFONE'=>$this->getTelefone(),
        ':ENDERECO'=>$this->getEndereco(),
        ':CPF'=>$this->getCpf(),
        ':COMPLEMENTO'=>$this->getComplemento(),
        ':NUMERO'=>$this->getNumero(),
        ':BAIRRO'=>$this->getBairro(),
        ':CIDADE'=>$this->getCidade(),
        ':ESTADO'=>$this->getEstado(),
        ':CEP'=>$this->getCep()
    ));

    if (count($results) > 0){

        $this->setData($results[0]);
    }

}

<?php

class Sql extends PDO {

    private $conn;
    private $dbHost   = "localhost";
    private $dbUsername = "root";
    private $dbPassword = "";
    private $dbName     = "banco_bd";

    public  function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->dbHost . ";dbname=" . $this->dbName . ";charset=utf8", $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);

    }

    private function setParams($statement, $parameters = array()) {

        foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {

            $this->setParam($statement, $key , $value);
        }

    }

    private function setParam($statement, $key, $value) {

        $statement->bindParam($key, $value);

    }

    public function query($rawQuery, $params = array()) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($rawQuery);

        $this->setParams($stmt, $params);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;

    }


    public function select($rawQuery, $params = array()):array
    {

        $stmt = $this->query($rawQuery, $params);

        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

}
?>
```

**PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`usuario`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_clientes_insert`(
    pnome varchar(255),
    pemail varchar(255),
    psenha varchar(255),
    ptelefone varchar(255),
    pendereco varchar(255),
    pcpf varchar(14),
    pnumero varchar(50),
    pcomplemento varchar(100),
    pbairro varchar(255),
    pcidade varchar(255),
    pestado varchar(2),
    pcep varchar(8)
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO clientes (nome, email, senha, telefone, endereco, cpf, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, estado, cep, notas)
    values (pnome, pemail, psenha, ptelefone, pendereco, pcpf, pnumero, pcomplemento, pbairro, pcidade, pestado, pcep, pnotas);

SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

END
```

Comment: No insert da sua `procedure` existe um campo chamado `pnotas`, mas você não está passando ele no `array`, você precisa verificar isso.

Comment: Amigo, ative o modo de exceções do PDO. Assim, toda vez que tiver algum erro referente a consulta, irá disparar informações contento o erro e você vai encontrar a solução facilmente. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, as duas resposta realmente resolveram o meu problema. obrigado.